# Using sed, how can I delete all instances of a string within a range of lines?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I know that

```
sed '/match/ d' file
```

deletes all lines with matches, and

```
sed '1,3 s/match//g' file
```

deletes all matches in the first 3 lines.

But how do I delete all lines with matches in first 3 lines?

If possible, give a solution with only one sed call (no piping).

Comment: `sed '1,3 { /match/d; }'`

Comment: You cannot use sed to replace instances of a string, only a regexp. To replace a string you need awk or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine the two:

```
sed '1,3{/match/d;}' file
```

This would delete lines containing `match` in the specified address range, i.e. in lines 1-3 in the example above.

Comment: +1 just make it `sed '1,3{/match/d;}' file` for BSD version of sed

Comment: @anubhava Added the `;` too.  Wonder why they use BSD sed at all.

Comment: Because OSX is shipped with it, I have installed gnu-sed using `home brew` but usually folks keep just the default one.

Comment: @anubhava I know.  Not only OSX, BSD (and variants) to have BSD sed.

Comment: @anubhava In POSIX, a sed function's right bracket (amongst other things) must be preceded by a newline or by a semicolon. Though it doesn't hurt to be present for GNU variants. So +1 for portable solution.

Comment: What importance do the `{}` play in this?  Yesterday, I was struggling and found a ridiculous workaround to this very problem.  I say ridiculous because yesterday I didn't find this.  I was using `sed "4,$ /match/ d" file` which was not producing what I wanted.  Please explain this difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to test `awk`, it would be:

```
awk '/match/ && NR<=3 {next} 1' file
```

Comment: ...or more generally, `awk 'NR < s || NR > e || !/match/' file`, where `s` and `e` are the start and end of your line range.

Comment: No problem. It's probably more readable the other way round: `'!(s <= NR && NR <= e && /match/)'`. Because awk is _all_ about readability!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v string="foo" 'NR<=3 && index($0,string) {next} 1' file
```